Image vertical alignement with tabularx
I have two (02) columns in a table, with width as linewidth so I used tabularx.
First column has mixed text (Arabic and French), aligned to the left.
Second column has an image.
I would like to have the image vertically and horizontally centered, but I just get the result that you see in the screenshot (image above and text after it).
How could I solve that?
Thanks in advance.
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt, fleqn]{report}

\usepackage[LAE, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic, english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\sisetup{
     detect-all,
     output-decimal-marker={,},
     group-minimum-digits = 3,
     group-separator={~},
     number-unit-separator={~},
     inter-unit-product={~},
     list-separator = {, },
     list-final-separator = { et },
     range-phrase = --,
     separate-uncertainty = true,
     multi-part-units = single,
     list-units = single,
     range-units = single
 }

\usepackage{boldline}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{  X V{5} c }
\clineB{1-1}{5}
\begin{flushright}
\scriptsize{
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
بلد بلا بلا بلا
\end{otherlanguage}

Pays de bla bla bla

\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
وزارة شيئا
\end{otherlanguage}

Ministère d'un truc
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
جامعة تارتبيون
\end{otherlanguage}

Université de tartempion

\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
كلية لاتيكس
\end{otherlanguage}

Faculté de latex

\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
قسم تبادل المكدس
\end{otherlanguage}

Département de Stack Exchange}
\end{flushright}

&
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm, valign=c, margin=4pt]{Figures/Logo_University.jpg}
            \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SE.

you can put the logo in its own table, and have 2 adjacent tabulars. So both must be single column tabulars. Is the simplest solution.
